# How to search users from firestore database using reactjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can get and display usernames.i just want to filter using search .Im using reactjs and firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out

```
{athletes
        .filter((athlete) => {
          if (search === "") {
            return athlete;
          } else if (
            athlete.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
          ) {
            return athlete;
          }
        })

        .map((athlete, key) => (
          <AthleteCard
            key={key}
            athlete={athlete}
            selectedAthletes={athletesForm}
            updateAthletesForm={updateAthletesForm}
          />
        ))}
```